# Unidirectional data flow: alleviating rework when dealing with a huge list of items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux, re-frame

Unidirectional data flow (Flux) as I understand how to use it appears ill-suited to a particular use case.  We have a SPA that displays a list of several hundred calendar entries for the entire month.  Each entry summarize a few details.

The UI allows the user to expand an entry by clicking it to expose additional details.  This is a simple matter of toggling an `expanded` bit on an entry in the model.

The part of flux that bothers me is that every user action requires the entire re-rendering of view model which then gets reconciled with the DOM.  So to toggle a bit on a single entry among hundreds triggers quite a bit of rework, regenerating hundreds of other entries to which no changes have been made, in order to accommodate the change on the one.

There must be a way of delivering the update message to the right mailbox to avoid unnecessary rework.  I know that React uses keys in attempt to optimize how the view model gets reconciled against the DOM, but even with this optimization the entire view model gets fully regenerated on any action.  I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible to display a list of thousands of items if message routing and DOM reconciliation were better.

I am working on an idea to address this.  My approach uses a version of memoization that caches view models from the prior rendering.  I am interested in learning from the innovations of others.

Answer (score 1):

The React-Redux library provides a `connect` function, which generates wrapper components that handle subscribing to the Redux store.  `connect` implements a *lot* of optimizations to ensure that the wrapped component only re-renders when actually necessary.  There's also some specific patterns you can use to help optimize re-rendering.  The main one is to have a connected list component passing item IDs to connected children, which look up their own data using that ID.  Finally, memoized "selector" functions, usually created with the Reselect library, can help cut down on re-renders as well.

The [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links) has a number of articles on this topic, as does the [Redux FAQ question on "scaling Redux"](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-scaling).  The article ["High Performance Redux"](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/) is particularly informative, and there was also a [good performance benchmark comparing Redux vs MobX](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/5hf4d4/an_artificial_example_where_mobx_really_shines/) earlier this week.

Answer (score 0):

suggesting use of redux-saga to address problem.please refer below links

[redux sage][1]https://shift.infinite.red/using-redux-saga-to-simplify-your-growing-react-native-codebase-2b8036f650de#.yz91g1rn2